# Phantom Edge on one side of symmetrical model

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]So I'm working on making a tank model for a class project and in setting up to for the extrusion across the hull of the tank, one side I get this phantom edge on the model with no edge between points.

The other side has the exact same points but does not have this little extra triangle. Am I missing something?

I already had to restart this because I managed to duplicate my points thousands of times without ever realizing it, not even trying to figure that one out, but that also had the same issue of an edge in the model where there was not one in the wireframe.

EDIT:I added the image, on the left side you can see a bit of a shaded part on the angle, that shouldn't be there and the right side doesn't have it so I am not sure why it is there nor how to get rid of it.

Comment: do you mean there is an edge visible in object mods, but not edit mode?

Comment: A couple of things to try: 1. Select Non-Manifold. This will show any geometry that doesn't form a volume. It can reveal problem areas. 2. Ctrl L to Select Linked, then H to Hide. This will hide the majority of your mesh, and if any parts are unconnected you will see them. After dealing with the unconnected parts you can un-hide with Alt H.

Comment: @David You can see the picture now for what I mean. In the model its there but I never made an edge to have it be there and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Comment: Oh, seeing your screen shot now, I'd say it's caused by your quad being concave. When you go beyond 180° inward like that weird things can happen.

Comment: @Mentalist mentioning that I was able to fix it, I went back and removed an edge to remove the face then add it back but also a new one to make 2 different triangles, that took care of it, wasn't thinking of it in that way so thanks.

Comment: Cool :-) Glad to hear you got it sorted.